# How to install-and boot-Ubuntu on my MacPro Tower?

Tags: system-installation

I'm running Mac OSX 10.6.8, have NO intention of moving to 10.7 or 10.8, since Apple is turning the platform into a "toy" system with too many restrictions.

So, for the past 8 months or so, I've been doing some exploratory "tunneling" to try to escape this---Ubuntu LOOKS pretty good, (running the web-based demo...) and I've even gotten it to install and run in a "virtual machine" [Oracle-VirtualBox].

it cannot "touch" the Mac hardware. So, I have no access to the NVIDIA card I've put into my MacPro, in the hope of accessing it, and it's "CUDA" GPU-parallel processing, to do rendering in BLENDER... Apple "of course" has disavowed NVIDIA, and there are no OSX drivers for NVIDIA cards... Hence my need to "natively" boot LINUX (Ubuntu, or any other "distro" that WILL boot my hardware)...

Does anybody have a working "recipe" on how to get rEFIt to work properly? (I'm a total idiot/newbie with command-line "stuff")

Or, is there a GUI-based "patch" that exists, that I can apply to fix this boot-loader related problem?

Answer (score 1):

That is definetely going to be a difficult process. Here is some information that may help you :

[**Installing Ubuntu on a Mac Pro**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacPro) (fetched from help.ubuntu.com )

- It is strongly suggested to use the Ubuntu 64 bits version (AMD64) to benefit from the full installed memory. Using the 32 bits will limit the memory to less than 3 Gb. The normal installation has been working seemlessly for a [MacPro3,1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacPro3) with Hardy (8.04 LTS), Jaunty (9.04) and Karmic (9.10).
- The regular 64-bit Ubuntu CDs have trouble booting on older Intel Macs, such as [MacPro1,1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacPro1), due to EFI incompatibilities. You must download a special +mac CD of Ubuntu to work-around this problem. For 11.04, you can get it here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/release/

  If you try to use a regular 64-bit Ubuntu CD on such systems, you may get the following blocking message while trying to boot off the CD:
  1.
      2.
      Select CD-ROM Boot type:
- **WARNING:** It is important to install the Grub boot loader on the Ubuntu partition (e.g. /dev/sda3), instead of the default disk root. This is done by selecting the Advanced options after partitioning and before the actual installation.

  By default, Ubuntu installs the GRUB boot loader on the disk root (e.g. dev/sda). This does modify the EFI and GUID boot loader, which then potentially removes your Mac OSX boot.... :( You must specify a partition for GRUB installation, e.g. /dev/sda3

  ***Features & Support status:***

  Sensors(Temps & fans) - Works out of the box

  Reboot - works out of the box

  Video & Effects (Compiz) - needs manual install

  HFS|HFS+ (only read) - works out of the box

  CDDVD|CD/DVD Writing - works out of the box

  Bluetooth|Bluetooth - works, with remarks

  Keyboard functions (Brightness,volume,...) - works, with remarks

  Ethernet - works, with remarks

  Wireless - works out of the box

  Sound - needs manual install

  Firewire - not yet documented
- **Quick Install Quide:**

  Note: The best version of Ubuntu to use is 10.04.2, as 10.10 has issues with [PulseAudio](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PulseAudio).

  1. Get a wired USB keyboard and mouse to make the install easy. Before you install Ubuntu, if you have OSX running it is strongly advised that you use system updates to insure that your various firmwares are up to date (bluetooth,wifi,EFI). In particular your EFI firmware must be the latest version. See

  http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1237

  2. When you power on hold down the left mouse button as soon as hearing the chime sound until the CD drive opens. Drop in Ubuntu 10.04.2 / 64bit / desktop edition. Reboot, and this time hold the "c" key down after the chime sound to boot from the CD in the drive.

  3. Boot into the live CD at the option screen. Not the install option.

  4. Go to Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal. Then type

  ```
  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda
  ```

  This will delete all your files and your operating system currently on your hard drive. Since we only want to wipe the first few hundred MB of data at the beginning of the drive wait 2 minutes, then press Ctrl-C. The output should show how much of the drive was 'zeroed' or wiped, which gives you an indication of the transfer speed of that drive BTW.

  5. Go to System -> Administration -> gparted

  Now, Device -> New Partition Table.

  Select msdos partition and press OK. This gives the BIOS on the Mac Pro a partition table it can boot from. If you don't do this, your new install will not boot when complete.

  6. Finally double click the install button on the desktop. Select manual partitioning when the option comes up during the install. Click free space -> Add -> select the filesystem type as reiser or ext4 (your preference, google it, reiser is better for most) and the mountpoint is "/" without the commas. Click OK and continue and ignore the message about no swap partition, most are better off without it.

  7. Start by setting up your wifi / network connection (network manager icon top right). The next thing you should do is System -> Administration -> Update Manager and install all of the updates and then reboot. Next go to System -> Administration -> Hardware Drivers and install all of the closed source drivers for graphics cards and such. It is best to install restricted drivers for network and wifi cards last of all. Reboot after this also. If you want the restricted video codecs so you can play all media go to System -> Administration -> Synaptic. Quick search for restricted. Right click ubuntu-restricted-extras and mark for installation. Click Apply on the top bar.

  8. To enable the sound on the headphone jack on the back facing side of the machine Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal. Now type

  ```
   sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
  ```

  and scroll to the end of the file and add the line:

  ```
  options snd-hda-intel model=imac24
  ```

  Save and reboot. From here on the Mac Pro will run like any other Ubuntu install. Done.

  **Keyboard**

  Beware to specify the Macintosh keyboard layout during installation. Using the Mac Aluminium keyboard may cause troubles. If you ever switch to NumLock and your keyboard goes crazy Tongue out :-? press the F6 key for 1-2 secs. Multimedia keys (F7-F12 for basck/forward/volume control) and Eject keys work out of the box.

  **Video**

  By default, the Vesa driver will be installed from the Ubuntu CD. This works OK. However, if you wish to speed-up display efficiency, and access 3D acceleration for e.g. OpenGL and Compiz, you should install the ad-hoc video driver.

  The MacPro3,1 ATI card is an ATI XT2600HD. There are lots of artifacts. Using ATI drivers. During boot, the splash screen has a bunch of white flickering pixels.

  Usually, the menu System/Administration/Hardware drivers should do well in most cases. Alternatively, you may try to install the required drivers using EnvyNG, which comes as a set of packages in the universe repositories: envyng-core, envyng-qt, envyng-gtk.

  (X) WARNING: on Karmic, the ATI driver installation crashes the machine ; this can only be fixed by removing the radeon drivers, and returning to the default vesa driver. In a few words, avoid installing the proprietary drivers for the ATI card under Karmic. The only way to install the driver is to use EnvyNG.

  The nvidia v180 drivers installed and worked fine for X, but the console will be flaky unless you build "vesafb" into the kernel and use a boot option that provides 1024x768 resolution

  **Bluetooth**

  The Apple bluetooth module in the Mac Pro works without issue under Ubuntu 10.04. However at boot the following error message is displayed and logged since the module connects to the USB bus.

  kernel 2.6.32-24-generic : [ 5.522591] hub 5-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 3

  **Sound**

  For the HDA Realtek ALC885/intel sound, the default installation does not enable sound output. An easy solution is to edit:

      sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

  and add at the end:

      options snd-hda-intel model=imac24

  This is the only option that works. Other model=macpro is not effective. Currently Only the back sound output port is working properly. The front audio port does not output at full volume. Better than nothing :)) .

  **Ethernet**

  A few ethernet issues have been reported (see below). Beware there are 2 ethernet plugs.

  **Wifi**

  Wifi Automatic installation

  The Wifi card is a BCM 4328. It is usually well detected from the Administration/Hardware Drivers which should see a Broadcom STA wireless driver.

  It seems the SSB module may require to be unactivated in some cases, e.g. with

  sudo modprobe -r ssb
  sudo modprobe wl

  then add wl at the end of file /etc/modules

  Wifi Manual installation from Broadcom

  Manual install can be done using Broadcom proprietary drivers and following the README.

  Wifi Manual installation using ''Ndiswrapper''

  Alternative is to use NdisWrapper

      wget http://ftp.us.dell.com/network/R151517.EXE
      mkdir driver
      unzip -a R151517.EXE -d driver/
      cd driver/DRIVER/
      sudo ndiswrapper -i bcmwl5.inf
      sudo ndiswrapper -l
      sudo ndiswrapper -m
      sudo modprobe ndiswrapper

  then add ndiswrapper at the end of /etc/modules

  Create file /etc/init.d/ndiswrapper with content:

      ### BEGIN INIT INFO
      # Provides: ndiswrapper
      # Required-Start:
      # Required-Stop:
      # Default-Start: S
      # Default-Stop:
      # Short-Description: enable to load ndiswrapper
      # Description: enable to load ndiswrapper
      ### END INIT INFO
      rmmod ohci_hcd
      rmmod ssb
      rmmod ndiswrapper
      modprobe ndiswrapper
      modprobe ssb
      modprobe ohci_hcd
      ############# end file ############

  Make it executable and start it as a boot process service with

      sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/ndiswrapper
      sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/ndiswrapper /etc/rc2.d/S99ndiswrapper

  **Other related links**:

  - http://mindbat.com/?p=30
  - http://macprolinux.blogspot.com/
  - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook%20Aluminum
  - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Intel_iMac
  - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation

**Related Askubuntu.com questions:**

- [Installing Ubuntu on macbook pro 9-1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177820/installing-ubuntu-on-macbook-pro-9-1)
- [Installing Ubuntu on macpro late 2011](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105574/install-ubuntu-on-macbook-pro-late-2011)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Using balenaEtcher to flash an Ubuntu Server 20.04 ISO to an USB install USB stick works on Mac Pro 3.1. Despite other posts claiming this as difficult on a Mac Pro 3.1 I succeeded today with a quite simple straightforward procedure.

- used a MacBook Pro M1 under MacOS Monterey to format a USB stick as FAT32, GUID Partition Table
- downloaded ubuntu-20.04.5-live-server-amd64.iso from Ubuntu download servers and checked the SHA checksum.
- used balenaEtcher.app V1.14.3 from https://www.balena.io/etcher to burn the image to the USB stick
- USB stick in Mac Pro 3.1 standard USB 2.0 slot
- 1TB SSD is in SATA bay 1
- reboot Mac Pro with Alt pressed into Boot Disk Selector
- select EFI USB Volume
- boot
- Ignore errors and press Enter and be patient; it takes a lot of time using USB 2.0
- You now may run smoothly through the setup confirming everything until a final reboot and a running system.
- Main settings to be done:

  - Select country and keyboard layout
  - Setup user and initial password
  - confirm basic disk layout (use or skip encryption as you like)
  - Select basic OpenSSH install
  - Skip other install stuff
  - Wait until Installation completed! shows up at the top of the screen.
- reboot after removing the USB-Stick
- Write down your local IP to login via SSH

#### History

The machine was already running under Ubuntu Server 18.04 hosting a BigBlueButton instance for some years before, but the SSD disk was wiped accidentally and the old procedure failed to finish the upgrade path from a block based image backup to Ubuntu Server 20.04.

The original install procedure was based on using a specially patched DVD with Ubuntu 16.04 working around EFI issues for an older Mac Pro1.1 and Upgrade later to Ubuntu 18.04 from the terminal.

For the BBB 2.6 version I needed explicitly an Ubuntu 20.04 release.

I tried to burn a new DVD from the ubuntu-20.04.5-live-server-amd64.iso file (Checksum checked twice!) but my MacBook Pro 14" M1 under Monterey refused to burn the ISO with an external USB 2.0 Apple Superdrive. The drive was listed in System Profiler properly and could generally burn DVDs but either the Finder right-click method or the Disk Utility.app method failed with "This is not a valid image". This is reported as a general issue since Catalina.

I avoided to use the deprecated UNetbootin tool, that is reported to be unreliable. Especially it is reported in breaking a serious amount of existing installs while running installers created by this tool.